# Offset for table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, offset

I have the same two tables on my UIViewController, which in UINavigationController. I don't understand why second table has offset.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableLeft;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableRight;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the autolayouts? It appears that your navigation bar is overtaking your right table view.

Comment: can you post your table scale view. and what is auto layout ?

Comment: @MiloGosnell I turn off autolayout. I don't need it. How can I solve my problem without autolayout?

Comment: can you show the frame of table2 ?

Comment: It looks like it may be an issue with your navigation controller. And as @Horst suggested, make sure the frames are the same.

Comment: @Horst this is frames two tables 
<UITableView: 0xa8ece00; frame = (0 0; 160 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e29860>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e27fd0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

<UITableView: 0xa8f1200; frame = (160 0; 160 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e2aad0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e27550>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: And it also looks like you have auto layout turned on. Check your constraints.

Comment: @MiloGosnell no, it turned off.

Comment: this issue is occur on >=ios 7.0 so put this one:
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7){
        secondtableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0);
    }

Comment: one other way you can set the self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; but you have to set frame of x position of UITabeleview(s).

Comment: @DhavalBhadania thank you, I set self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; and it works.